# How to get user profile in LinkedIn?

Tags: api, oauth, linkedin-api

How can I get the profile of a user on LinkedIn?
Please specify the API and how to get authenticated through that API.
Please specify the complete procedure.

Comment: See for yourself in the Docs: https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/signin-with-linkedin

Answer (score 2):

Take a look here for more info:

https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/linkedin/shared/integrations/people/profile-api?context=linkedin/consumer/context

Comment: none of the above link is working

Answer (score 0):

Check out the docs: http://developer.linkedin.com/docs/DOC-1008

Comment: Neither Your link Works