# How to get linkedin user id from profile url

Tags: android

I would like to get linkedin user id from user profile url.

I have the user public profile url. 
I need to fetch the id for that repestive user.
So that I can call linkedin app with the user profile from my app.

Answer (score -4):

refer below links, might be proved helpful to you.

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_linkedin_integration.htm

http://www.3pillarglobal.com/insights/part-2-using-socialauth-to-integrate-linkedin-api-in-android

https://github.com/mukesh4u/Android-LinkedIn-Demo

[How to get user profile in LinkedIn?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3664442/how-to-get-user-profile-in-linkedin)

Comment: I have intergrated linkedin already. And I have access token too. I have linkedin profile url of a user, from which i want to get his/her user id.

Comment: here there is a link give user profile pic,                         [link](http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/{user-id}/picture-url), so now just replace "pictue-url" tag in a link with "your_user_name" tag.                                                                                                                                                                                                                             for more details : [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6955647/getting-linkedin-profile-picture)