# How to easily get full user profile in LinkedIn?

Tags: json, api, linkedin-api

Is there an simple way to query all fields in a JSON response, from a linkedin profile without requesting fields individually, or is there another, consumer side, approach that would render all data in a delimited way?

The closest [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3664442/how-to-get-user-profile-in-linkedin) had broken links.

Answer (score 0):

Im currently dealing with the same issue. In my app I need to access whole profile of a user nut if you dont have  partnership with LinkedIn this is not possible. The closest I get so far is asking user to [export his profile as an archive](https://www.linkedin.com/psettings/member-data) (Im OK with the fast option there) and then in my app Im using [JSON Resume](https://github.com/JMPerez/linkedin-to-json-resume) to convert this archive to JSON.

But if someone has better idea dont be shy to share it ;)

Hope that help at least a little